# How to get current date and time of App Installation date in Android

Tags: android

I want to get Android Application Installation Date in Android.But when i run the app getting NullPointerException.Can someone help me.

Here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_details);

        try 
        {        long installed = 
                 context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("package.com.sqlitedemo",          
                 PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).firstInstallTime;
                 Log.e("installed  = ","  "  + installed);
        }
        catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Here is my Log Cat Error

```
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sqlitedemo/com.sqlitedemo.Registration_Form}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.sqlitedemo.Registration_Form.onCreate(Registration_Form.java:61)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-06 11:40:34.758: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks to appreciate.

Comment: which line is Registration_Form.java:61 ?

Comment: I suppose its context.getPackageManager(), which is returning null. Have you initialized context like `context = this;` after `setContentView`? Can't see that in code.

Comment: @Mann ,The line Registration_Form.java:61 = long installed = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("package.com.sqlitedemo", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).firstInstallTime;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("package.com.sqlitedemo"
```

instead of

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.sqlitedemo"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a calendar instance on your splash or main activity and can save it in shared preference like below--

```
    SharedPreference shared=getSharedPreferences(Preference.KEY_PREF,MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor  edit=shared.edit();
        if(shared.getBoolean(Preference.KEY_FIRST_TIME, false)==false){
            edit.putBoolean(Preference.KEY_FIRST_TIME,true );
            Calendar first=Calendar.getInstance();
            edit.putLong(Preference.KEY_FIRST_DATE, first.getTimeInMillis());
```

this will store the date,time etc whenever your app runs for first time

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `context`, so its returning null.

Change your code to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.registration_details);
context = this;
try 
{        
    long installed = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("package.com.sqlitedemo",          
                 PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).firstInstallTime;
    Log.e("installed  = ","  "  + installed);
}
```

So your context will not return null anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think ur context is null ..

```
Context context;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration_details);
    context=getBaseContext();
    try 
    {        long installed = 
             context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("package.com.sqlitedemo",          
             PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).firstInstallTime;
             Log.e("installed  = ","  "  + installed);
    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

may it helps

Regards